# Copying (using assignment) a structure to a structure inside a union causing seg fault

Tags: c++, struct, memcpy, unions

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

struct bar
{
  std::string s3;
  std::string s4;
}Bar;

union foo
{
  char * s1;
  char * s2;
  bar    b1;

  foo(){};
  ~foo(){};
}Foo;


int main ()
{
  foo f1;
  bar b2;

  std::string temp("s3");
  b2.s3 = temp;
  b2.s4 = temp;

  //f1.b1 = b2;                           //-- This Fails (Seg faults)

  /*
    #0  0x00002b9fede74d25 in std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&) [clone .part.12] ()
        from /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
    #1  0x00002b9fede75f09 in std::string::assign(std::string const&) () from /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
    #2  0x0000000000400ed1 in bar::operator= (this=0x7fff3f20ece0) at un.cpp:5
    #3  0x0000000000400cdb in main () at un.cpp:31
  */

  memcpy( &f1.b1, &b2, sizeof(b2) );  //-- This Works 

  std::cout << f1.b1.s3 << " " << f1.b1.s4 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Can you please explain why the segmentation fault ? I am unable to decipher what that the data in the back trace suggests.

Comment: @Wilding: The code does not compile.

Comment: Yes it does. Please check again. I compiled like this: `g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 un.cpp -o u`

Comment: I have compiled it over VS2013.

Comment: Can you paste the error please ?

Comment: Error 2 error C2039: 'b1' : is not a member of 'foo' main.cpp 41 1 
Error 3 error C2039: 'b1' : is not a member of 'foo' main.cpp 43 1 
Error 4 error C2228: left of '.s3' must have class/struct/union main.cpp 43 1 
Error 5 error C2228: left of '.s4' must have class/struct/union main.cpp 43 1

Comment: maybe defining structs and unions and structs is a little different on VS. Some semicolon issue or something ? You should be able to fix it I think .. Let me know what the issue was if you do not mind.

Comment: I don't think it will be different on VS. I didn't find any semicolon issues. The intellisense of VS showing error at bar    b1; declaration in union.

Comment: @Sumeet VS is not allowing you to add the variable bar to the union since there is not explicit constructor for the struct I think. But C++11 should allow this.

Comment: I think the compiler should know the size of the union during compile time. for ex.union myuni{string str;}; will not work, since the size of str may vary depending upon the size of string it stores. While same scenario union myuni{string *str;}; using pointer it will work. Since it knows that the pointer will take fix size.

Comment: probably true, but then I wonder why g++ allows it. Would you mind posting a question ? I do not have access to VS.

Comment: Ok. I will post the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764587/compilation-error-for-union

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`union foo` can't initialize the bar object (how does it know which member's initializer to call?) and consequently can't initialize the `std::string`s.  If you want to use the bar inside of foo, then you need to manually initialize it, like so...

```
new (&f1.b1) bar; // Placement new
f1.b1 = b2;
// And later in code you'll have to manually destruct the bar, because
//   foo doesn't know to destruct the bar either...
f1.b1.~bar();
```

Alternatively, you can try to roll this functionality into the union's constructors and destructors yourself.

```
foo() : b1() {}
// Or you construct like this, which you might need to for a non-trivial union...
// foo() { new (&b1) bar; }  // Placement new.
~foo() { b1.~bar(); }
```

Note that copying also needs special handling.

Comment: You solved it. Even though the other answers helped me a lot, this one is the actual answer to the problem. My code was fixed by simply adding `new (&f1.b1) bar;` before `f1.b1 = b2;`

Comment: Note that that just adding placement new leaks.  The bar object (and thus its strings) will never destruct unless you manually do so.

Comment: Yes I took care of it. Added the allocation and de allocation to the constructor and destructor ..

Comment: Actually... it may be bad to do the destructor.  If you were to use the union as a character pointer, it would invalidate the string data, which could wreck havoc on the now-initialized-and-needs-destroyed string data.

Honestly, it's impossible to say how to deal with your union without more details about what exactly it is you are trying to accomplish.  Unions in general are really tricky objects with very specific situational needs.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` has a non-trivial constructor, that initializes its internal members. Therefore, your `struct bar` is no POD structure.

Unions only support POD (this is relaxed in C++11). The compiler cannot decide which constructor of which of the union's members to call. Imagine following situation:

```
unition MyUnion {
  std::string s;
  std::vector v;
};
```

Should it use vector's or string's constructor to initialize the object?

So in your situation, when you assign the string to the union's string, the internal data is not initalized, which causes random errors.

Comment: Also, I am using `C++11`

Comment: It's just not possible. Even in C++11, it only works on simple constructors. Take a look at Bjarne Stroustrups C++11 FAQ regarding this issue: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#unions

Answer (score 1):

You can't use memcpy to copy objects or structure containing objects because they will not be properly initialized. Strings have pointers to char arrays, and if two strings can share the same pointer, there must be some kind of garbage collection (typically a reference counter). If you do f1.b1 = b2, the compiler will generate the code to initialize the strings correctly.

Comment: But Maurice, I cannot do `f1.b1 = b2` as std::string has a non trivial constructor. What are my options here ?

Comment: I think you should rethink your data structure. One thing is for sure, you can only initialize the first field of a union. Provider that b1 is the first field of Foo, you would initialize f1 as follows: Foo f1 = {Bar()};

Comment: Wildling, you can use C++11 and then read very, very, very, very carefully the extensions for unions. But it's the kind of thing where if you ask on stackoverflow, you probably shouldn't use it.

Comment: @gnasher729 Maybe, but with unions I always feel that I am not using them enough.