# Compilation error for union

Tags: c++, unions

can somebody please explain why the following program causing the compilation problem. I have compiled the source code over VS2013.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Do not work
union myuni
{
    string str;
};

void main()
{

}
```

Does union require the fixed length size while declaring it? The same scenario works fine with structure.

Comment: Non POD types in unions are only allowed since c++11.

Comment: @tgmath And even in C++11, you'd need user defined constructors, etc.,  which in turn use placement new to initialize the correct member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have a `string` in a `union` as the former contains a constructor.

(Although allowed in C++11 this is not supported in VS2013).