# gcc std::vector _M_start bigger then _M_Finish

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, stdvector

when examining the information from a core-file generated by a segmentation fault I noticed that the cause of the crash is that an std::vector is trying to emplace_back an object at the adress 0x1.

It looks like this:

```
print myvec
$1 = [...] = {
    _M_impl = {<std::allocator<Action>> = [...], _M_start = 0x60, _M_finish = 0x1, _M_end_of_storage = 0x31}}, <No data fields>}
```

What I noticed is that _M_start is bigger then _M_finish which doesn't make sense at all, as the size of a vector is calculated as

```
size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
```

which would mean that the size is "negative". So no wonder it crashes, but I do have no idea why that is? What could be the cause of such behavior? I already double checked and I don't try to link corrupted or old library files together.

The value type of the vector contains an union, but the data of it seems to be correct when I print it. Do you have any ideas how to further proceed with debugging this?

Comment: Sounds like the vector is not valid.  That could be because you moved it, the objects that holds it went of scope, you have a pointer to the vector and the pointer no longer points to a valid vector.  It also might not even be the vectors fault.  If your code has UB anywhere in it that is called, then that could affect the vector.

Comment: All the pointers look completely wrong. Either your vector has become corrupted for some reason, or it has been destroyed, or it was never valid to begin with. The cause is somewhere in the rest of our code.

Comment: if the vector is a class field then you are referencing a dangling pointer to object of that class. So inspect your call stack for use of invalid pointers. You need provide more details about your code if you are ask for a help.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but for everyone interested it was because I made a mistake in the copy constructor of the wrapper around the union. For anyone stumbling upon this, here is the answer I found that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22763779/10911886